# How do I keep search results consistent in a netbeans swing outline (tree table) after it gets sorted?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

The search I'm trying to implement is a google-chrome-like type of search with all matches highlighted in yellow and the current match highlighted in orange, and it's possible to navigate forward with Enter or backwards with Shift+Enter. The Swing component that I'm using is the Netbeans Swing Outline which basically looks like a JTree Table.  It works until the outline is sorted by clicking on any of its column. For this example, there's only one column.

To make this example work we need the outline jar from the Netbeans distribution located here netbeans\platform\modules\org-netbeans-swing-outline.jar. 
Another option is to place this Gradle build file (build.gradle) at the root of the Gradle project :

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
}

dependencies {
    compile 'uk.gov.nationalarchives.thirdparty.netbeans:org-netbeans-swing-outline:7.2'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

The tree model has a search feature findNodesWithPattern that puts the search into a list :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeNode;

public class TestTreeModel extends DefaultTreeModel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public TestTreeModel() {
        super(buildModel());
    }

    private static TreeNode buildModel() {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("");
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode node = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("test" + i);
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                node.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("subtest" + j));
            }
            root.add(node);
        }
        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public DefaultMutableTreeNode getRoot() {
        return (DefaultMutableTreeNode) super.getRoot();
    }

    public List<TreeNode> findNodesMatchingPattern(Pattern pattern) {
        List<TreeNode> matchingNodes = new ArrayList<>();
        findNodesWithpattern(matchingNodes, getRoot(), pattern);
        return matchingNodes;
    }

    private void findNodesWithpattern(List<TreeNode> matchingNodes, TreeNode node, Pattern pattern) {
        if (pattern.matcher(node.toString()).find()) {
            matchingNodes.add(node);
        }
        Enumeration<DefaultMutableTreeNode> children = node.children();
        while (children.hasMoreElements()) {
            findNodesWithpattern(matchingNodes, children.nextElement(), pattern);
        }
    }

}
```

There is also a row model which defines one column named Value with the hash code of the object (for demo purpose only)

```
import org.netbeans.swing.outline.RowModel;

public class TestRowModel implements RowModel {
    @Override
    public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
        return Integer.class;
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return "Value";
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueFor(Object node, int column) {
        return node.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(Object node, int column) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueFor(Object node, int column, Object value) {
        // do nothing for now
    }
}
```

The render which is in charge of highlighting in yellow or orange :

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException;

import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeNode;

import org.netbeans.swing.outline.RenderDataProvider;

public class TestRenderData implements RenderDataProvider {

    private String searchPattern;
    private TreeNode currentMatch;

    @Override
    public java.awt.Color getBackground(Object o) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getDisplayName(Object o) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) o;
        if (searchPattern == null || searchPattern.length() == 0) {
            return node.toString();
        }
        try {
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(" + searchPattern + ")");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(node.toString());
            Color bgColor = Color.YELLOW;
            if (matcher.find()) {
                if (node == currentMatch) {
                    bgColor = Color.ORANGE;
                }
            }
            String bgHexColor = Integer.toHexString(bgColor.getRGB() & 0xffffff);
            String replacement = matcher.replaceAll("<span style=\"background-color: #" + bgHexColor + "\">$1</span>");
            return "<html>" + replacement + "</html>";
        } catch (PatternSyntaxException e) {
            return node.toString();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public java.awt.Color getForeground(Object o) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public javax.swing.Icon getIcon(Object o) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getTooltipText(Object o) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isHtmlDisplayName(Object o) {
        return false;
    }

    public void setSearchPattern(String searchPattern) {
        this.searchPattern = searchPattern;
    }

    public void setCurrentMatch(TreeNode currentMatch) {
        this.currentMatch = currentMatch;
    }
}
```

The main class builds the outline with a quick filter (non-matching nodes are filtered out) and a key listener which triggers the search. When Enter key is typed, it increments a counter (nthMatch) and the current match at index nthMatch is highited in Orange by the renderer.

```
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;

import org.netbeans.swing.etable.QuickFilter;
import org.netbeans.swing.outline.DefaultOutlineModel;
import org.netbeans.swing.outline.Outline;
import org.netbeans.swing.outline.OutlineModel;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public MainFrame() {
        TestTreeModel treeMdl = new TestTreeModel();
        OutlineModel mdl = DefaultOutlineModel.createOutlineModel(treeMdl, new TestRowModel(), true, "Test");
        Outline outline = new Outline();
        TestRenderData renderData = new TestRenderData();
        outline.setRenderDataProvider(renderData);
        outline.setRootVisible(false);
        outline.setModel(mdl);
        JScrollPane jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(outline);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(outline);
        JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
        JLabel searchPatternLabel = new JLabel("  Search :  ");
        mb.add(searchPatternLabel);
        JTextField searchPatternTextField = new JTextField();
        searchPatternLabel.setLabelFor(searchPatternTextField);
        outline.setQuickFilter(0, new QuickFilter() {

            @Override
            public boolean accept(Object aValue) {
                if (searchPatternTextField.getText() == null || searchPatternTextField.getText().length() == 0) {
                    return true;
                }
                if (aValue instanceof DefaultMutableTreeNode) {
                    DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) aValue;
                    Enumeration<DefaultMutableTreeNode> children = node.children();
                    while (children.hasMoreElements()) {
                        DefaultMutableTreeNode child = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) children.nextElement();
                        if (accept(child)) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                    try {
                        Pattern searchPattern = Pattern.compile(searchPatternTextField.getText());
                        return searchPattern.matcher(node.toString()).find();
                    } catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        mb.add(searchPatternTextField);
        setJMenuBar(mb);
        getContentPane().add(jScrollPane1);
        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

        searchPatternTextField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

            private int nthMatch = 0;

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                    if (e.isShiftDown()) {
                        nthMatch--;
                    } else {
                        nthMatch++;
                    }
                }
                try {
                    Pattern searchPattern = Pattern.compile(searchPatternTextField.getText());
                    List<TreeNode> matchingNodes = treeMdl.findNodesMatchingPattern(searchPattern);
                    if (matchingNodes.size() > 0) {
                        if (nthMatch >= matchingNodes.size()) {
                            nthMatch = 0;
                        }
                        if (nthMatch < 0) {
                            nthMatch = 0;
                        }
                        TreeNode matchingNode = matchingNodes.get(nthMatch);
                        renderData.setCurrentMatch(matchingNode);
                        TreePath matchingNodePath = new TreePath(((DefaultMutableTreeNode) matchingNode).getPath());
                        outline.expandPath(matchingNodePath);
                        outline.scrollRectToVisible(outline.getPathBounds(matchingNodePath));
                        renderData.setSearchPattern(searchPatternTextField.getText());
                    }
                } catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {

                }
                //outline.repaint();
                treeMdl.nodeChanged(treeMdl.getRoot());
            }

        });

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new MainFrame();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

As a basic scenario, I look for "test" repeatedly by pressing Enter.
The order of the search results are messed up whenever a column is clicked for sorting.
There are 2 inherited methods convertRowIndexToModel and convertRowIndexToView in the Outline that seem to do an index mapping and but I have no idea how to use them.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever the search field changes, just inform the renderer of the new search pattern. This will take care of the highlight-in-yellow-as-you-type part:

```
searchPatternTextField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        renderData.setSearchPattern(searchPatternTextField.getText());
        treeMdl.nodeChanged(treeMdl.getRoot());
    }

    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        renderData.setSearchPattern(searchPatternTextField.getText());
        treeMdl.nodeChanged(treeMdl.getRoot());
    }

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        renderData.setSearchPattern(searchPatternTextField.getText());
        treeMdl.nodeChanged(treeMdl.getRoot());
    }
});
```

Then listen for Enter and Shift+Enter. Just lookup for previous, current, and next matching node in the view :

```
searchPatternTextField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

    private void showMatchingNode(TreeNode node) {
        renderData.setCurrentMatch(node);
        TreePath matchingNodePath = new TreePath(((DefaultMutableTreeNode) node).getPath());
        outline.expandPath(matchingNodePath);
        outline.scrollRectToVisible(outline.getPathBounds(matchingNodePath));
    }

    public TreeNode findNextMatchingNode(boolean lookForPrevious) {
        try {
            Pattern searchPattern = Pattern.compile(searchPatternTextField.getText());
            boolean currentMatchFound = false;
            TreeNode previousMatch = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < outline.getRowCount(); i++) {
                TreeNode node = (TreeNode) outline.getValueAt(i, 0);
                if (node == renderData.getCurrentMatch()) {
                    currentMatchFound = true;
                    if (previousMatch != null && lookForPrevious) {
                        return previousMatch;
                    }
                } else if (searchPattern.matcher(node.toString()).find()) {
                    if (renderData.getCurrentMatch() == null || (currentMatchFound && !lookForPrevious)) {
                        return node;
                    }
                    previousMatch = node;
                }
            }
        } catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
            TreeNode node = findNextMatchingNode(e.isShiftDown());
            if (node != null) {
                showMatchingNode(node);
            }
            treeMdl.nodeChanged(treeMdl.getRoot());
        }
    }

});
```